# What is the CSS filter property and how does it work?

Tags: css, filtering

What is `filter: url(#Blur);` in CSS and how does it work?

Example:

```
.blur {
    filter: url(#Blur);
    -o-filter: blur(12px);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=10)";
    -webkit-filter: blur(12px);
    filter: blur(12px); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Quoting W3schools :

> The `url()` function takes the location of an XML file that specifies
>   an SVG filter, and may include an anchor to a specific filter element.

Example

```
filter: url(svg-url#element-id)
```